# Inaccurate output voltage from the Analog Multiplexer

Tags: analog, analog-switch

I am using the analog multiplexer "MAX337" in my design to get the voltage drop over a shunt resistor from 8 branches, then i use a "INA118" instrumental amplifier with 500 gain to get the value by an ESP8266, everything is working great but the analog multiplexer is adding little bit more voltage to the input voltage drop, for example if the voltage drop of the first branch shunt resistor is 2.236mV the output of the multiplexer is 2.399mV which is changing the over all result and it is the same with all the 8 inputs of the multiplexer....can you please tell me where is the mistake i am doing, and of course if you see anything done in a wrong way or can be don't i a better way in my design please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

[image: my design]

Comment: Demonstrate that you are not exceeding the common mode input range of the InAmp please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if the voltage drop of the first branch shunt resistor is 2.236mV the
> output of the multiplexer is 2.399mV*

The [MAX337](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX336-MAX337.pdf)'s input leakage current rapidly rises as the input closes-in on either supply rail. It can be as high a 1 μA (top of page 3) and, given that the on-resistance is around 400 Ω, that could account for ± 400 μV of extra input offset voltage you were not expecting to see.

Input (or port) leakage current needn't be regarded as flowing out of a pin; it can be regarded as flowing back through the multiplexer hence the volt-drop caused by its internal on-resistance. Clearly it can't obviously flow into the InAmp (except for reasons at the bottom of this answer) hence it has to flow somewhere and the only route is via the internal chip to the LED driver or the diodes.

You might also be approaching or exceeding the input voltage range of the InAmp too.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for you answer, with 500 gain the output of the amplifier was (1.172V) almost the minimum Input common-mode voltage (1.1v in the data sheet), so i rose up the gain to 650 and i got (1.65V), 1.65/650= 2.538mV and the actual drop voltage over the resistor is 2.298mV....should i accepted like this and subtract that difference(0.2mV) from the final result?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem does it. Try understanding what I'm saying.

Comment: ok sir i understand your explanations now but i don't know how can i solve it

Comment: @KamelK this is a question and answer site and you asked this: *can you please tell me where is the mistake i am doing* and I answered that. My opinion on a fix is to create a small negative supply for the InAmp and multiplexer but, realistically you may have different ideas about what direction you want to take hence, given that a neg supply is not always easy (or ideal) I can only suggest that to help you at least prove what the problem is.

Comment: ok sir thanks for you valuable opinion and your explanation...i will try to fix it and will let you know

Comment: @KamelK to meet site etiquette requirements, do you know what to do next regarding [accepting answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png)?

Comment: sorry i forgot that

Comment: @KamelK good luck and before jumping into a fix, check the result you get with a slight negative supply voltage such as -3 volts.